# There are m seats out of which n are to be occupied. Then the number of seating arrangements such that each person has exactly one neighbour.

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

There are m seats in a row out of which n are to be occupied by n persons. Given, m>2n and n is an even number. Find the number of seating arrangements such that each and every person has exactly one neighbour.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: And it helps if you phrase your question as a question